# I want to hide the keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, keyboard

i want to hide the keyboard but i want to write it in a class. To use it for all activities. ı need a edit text delete focus code

```
class Extensions(){
fun hideSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    val imm =getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

}

problem description

No value passed for parameter 'serviceClass'

Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Context was expected

**new code:** but I couldn't do the outer click event

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    val view = currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        view.clearFocus()
        val inputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            view.windowToken,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this about hiding a virtual (on-screen) keyboard, on a particular platform? If so, could you add a suitable tag? (For contrast, you couldn't hide _my_ keyboard with some code — you'd need a towel or something :-)

Comment: I am using the Kotlin language on android studio. I want to hide my keyboard with function code I wrote in a class

Comment: getSystemService needs to be called on a Context object.  Calling it like you did makes it look for a function with that name on the Extention class, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: no i did and it works i just click on the outer part i couldn't close it.
I shared it as new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions.kt

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard(event: MotionEvent) {
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        val view = currentFocus
        if (view != null) {
            view.clearFocus()
            val outRect = Rect()
            view.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
            if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                val inputMethodManager =
                    getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                    view.windowToken,
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

YouActivity

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        hideKeyboard(event)
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an Extenstion function on the edit text that would do that for you

```
fun EditText.hideKeyboard() {
    clearFocus()
    val imm = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0)
}
```

I haven't tested it out yet, please test that one out and tell me if it does work.

Comment: it worked but when i click the outer i want it.

Comment: not with a button click event. I also want to clear all the edit texts and all the focus.

Comment: 'fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    val view = currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        view.clearFocus()
        val inputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            view.windowToken,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
        )
    }
}'

Comment: this code hides all edittext but doesn't do outer click event

Answer (score 0):

// on below line getting current view.
val view: View? = this.currentFocus

```
        // on below line checking if view is not null.
        if (view != null) {
            // on below line we are creating a variable
            // for input manager and initializing it.
            val inputMethodManager =
                getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
             
            // on below line hiding our keyboard.
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0)
             
            // displaying toast message on below line.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Key board hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Jetpack Compose;

```
@Composable
fun MainScreenView(){

    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    keyboardController.hide()
```

Comment: No. I want to hide my keyboard and I want to remove focus of edit text. I just want to do this in a class.